# How should I do using multiple different two languages in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, json, express, multilingual

Can someone help me and can explain about this matter?
Currently, I'm just building a blog which I used which nodejs. In my projects, I want to use and display the two different languages which my local language and English.

As I showed up above like that website when I click change languages without showing like this example.com/mm. I'm just want to display like example.com without /mm or /en.

Example url: https://www.mmbusticket.com/

I'm not familiar with PHP. I'm the big fun of Nodejs.
How I have to do so for this case and which packages should I use for nodejs?

Thanks.

Comment: It really depends on how you have built your website, try looking into things like these: https://www.i18next.com/ , https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node

Answer (score 0):

An option for you is the [i18n module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n), and you can find similar options in many frontend frameworks as well. (You'll see this concept in app development too.)

The idea is that you have a directory with "locales" (the languages), each in a JSON file. The keys are the same in all locales. Like:

> `locales/en.json`

```
{
  "hello": "hello",
  "greeting": "hey there, {{name}}"
}
```

> `locales/mm.json` (used google translate, forgive me : )

```
{
  "hello": "ဟယ်လို",
  "greeting": "ဟေ့ဒီမှာ {{name}}"
}
```

In your app you'd do something like `i18n.localize("hello")` and depending on your current language setting (maybe passed in a cookie to the server if server-rendering, or set on the frontend page for client-side) you'll get the response.

Variables can be done above like `i18n.localize(['greeting', {name: "clay"}])` and that will fill in the passed parameter `name` into the string defined at `greeting`. You can typically do nesting and other cool things, depending on the library used.

Just note that you end up using these special "key strings" everywhere, so the code is a little messier to read. Name those keys wisely : ) And if you want to translate the entire contents of your blog, that's a different service entirely.

Comment: Oh! I see. Let me try to work with your instructions. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some example project to me in order to reference with your way. Thanks.